# lock orientation till a function get executed in order to resolve fragment transision commit error

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, screen-orientation

Trying to understand and implement below.
In MainActivity, calling a asynctask to download and render webView fragment. In onPostExecution(), I am calling below function which takes care of loading the fragment as shown in below. SelectionItem() from onPostExecute() is always called with position 0. for simplicity below code shows position 0. However SelectItem(position) has switch case in order to create different fragments.

```
     public void SelectItem(position) {

    Fragment fragment = null;
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    fragment = new FragmentFullPage();
    args.putInt(FragmentFullPage.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 1);
    args.putString("URLSTRING", urlString);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    FragmentManager frgManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = frgManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

Before calling asynctask I am initializing a variable handleorientation = true and resetting it as false once async task is complete

Implemented onConfigurationChange as below

```
         @Override
  public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
      super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
      if(handleOrientation == true) {
          if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
              setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
              Toast.makeText(this, "Keeping Portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
              setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
              Toast.makeText(this, "Keeping Landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }
      }
  }
```

and in manifest file taken care of android:configChanges="orientation".

But still when running screen is getting rotated and getting below error.

```
    08-15 15:43:16.657  26720-26720/com.srids.sathyasaiinspires E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1365)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1383)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:636)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:615)
        at com.srids.sathyasaiinspires.MainActivity.SelectItem(MainActivity.java:224)
        at com.srids.sathyasaiinspires.MainActivity$HandleWebPageLoad.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:160)
        at com.srids.sathyasaiinspires.MainActivity$HandleWebPageLoad.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:136)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

where MainActivity.SelectItem(MainActivity.java:224) is fragmentTransaction.commit();

Comment: if my answered worked for you, please accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you ask the current screen orientation before launching your `AsyncTask` and lock it till onPostExecute()? Try something like this before you start the background thread:

```
if(getActivity().getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE){
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
}
else{
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I have just tried and working fine. onPreexecute() locked as you mentioned and in onPostExecute() I called   setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED); Tested both landscape and portrait.

any SDK limitation for this solution? minimum support version testing is 14 and above

Comment: Happy it helped you. As I know this is working from API level 1, so there is no SDK limitation.